# How can I offload customer's data needs onto the customer?

Tags: database, data, repository, storage, crud

I write code for an Engineering application where engineers keep giving me various specs in a form of tabular data - for example, a table with product model names and many various parameters for each model.

Engineering is my "customer", since they use the code I create.

I usually encode the data they give me in a database, and build a CRUD interface around it to allow them to update/change/edit the data.  This was okay at first, but CRUD interfaces take work, and this programmer is lazy... and engineering keeps creating various new tabular data all the time.

I need a better solution, since this problem is essentially the same all the time but it takes a lot of work to implement and maintain every new occurrence of this problem.

**Solution 1 - keep creating CRUD interfaces**

Problems:

- data duplication:  the data lives in the Excel sheets used by Engineering AND in server's database.
- custom work:  I have to do a lot of work creating custom CRUD interfaces for yet another new table (forms, views, tables, JS/jQuery event handling, view/add/edit/delete scripts)

**Solution 2 - give customer direct access to database i.e. via a database viewer**

This requires training them on use of database, and also may not be security-conscious, and database access tools give too much access, i.e. you can delete historical records that otherwise must be preserved.

Neither are great solutions, and I am looking for a better approach to the problem.

Comment: cant you just import the excel sheet?

Comment: perhaps.  I have been thinking about that and may be the way to go forward.  It likely won't be as efficient or speedy as a database, and it won't have easily enforceable checks and balances (i.e. entering integers into strings and vv) but it *will* off-load data needs away from me and onto someone else

Comment: Can you find tools to auto-generate the CRUD interfaces?  I've seen such a feature in Visual Studio for web apps - not sure if that's applicable here.

Comment: Why store any of this in a database?  Does the data get used for something else or just CRUD?  If it's just CRUD, is there some reason a folder of shared Excel sheets or some Google sheets wouldn't work better?

Comment: data is used for an engineering program. I use PHP so wherever the data is stored, it has to be accessible from the server storage via PHP

Comment: "Solution 2" is IMHO unlikely to work. Find some RAD tool to create the CRUD interfaces with less effort. If you favor PHP, google for "rad php", you will find several solutions. But if the data goes into some standard database, there is no need to use the same programming language for the CRUD UI as for the server programs. You could also use some RAD tool like OpenXava (Java based) or RubyOnRails.

Comment: What database backend? Have you considered MS Access as a front end? In this situation it might give them enough independance and you can enforce datatypes and many rules. If you use linked tables you can control what they can delete. Data editing can be done in table view or via a form.

Comment: Backend is MySQL.  I have not considered MS Access for front end.  It may be an idea to try though.